# How can I set the local for moment in Vuetify?

Tags: momentjs, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify and I like to use also Momentjs.

I installed `vue-moment` and it works. But now, I like to change the local, and it always gives an error.

I tried to follow the manual of `momentjs` and `vue-moment`. But no success!

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './vuex'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const moment = require('moment')
require('moment/locale/de')

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'), {
  moment
})

console.log(Vue.moment().locale()) //en

new Vue({
  router: router,
  store: store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Without the local setting, it works well!

Is there something different in Vuetify?

Comment: If you are using vue-cli, the, you can use this: https://github.com/scottbedard/vue-cli-plugin-moment#readme.

Answer (score 0):

When I use moment I do :

```
import moment from "moment";
moment.locale("fr");
```

Comment: Do you user vuetify?

Comment: Yes I'm using vuetify with vomposition-api, I import moment, set the locale and then use it, for example as a computed property : ...
    const createdLocal = computed(() => {
      let date = moment
        .utc(data.created)
        .local()
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
      return moment(date).format("L HH:mm");
    }); ...